# Настроить доставку на Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

У меня опенкарт 2.1
У меня такой вопрос, возможно ли без модуля настроить доставку так, если цена будет меньше 500 рублей, то доставка была бесплатная.

Comment: конечно. надо лишь логику фри шипинга впилить в чекаут ;)

Comment: А можно более подробно ? на flat.php нужно встроить код фришипинга ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/s8793h не понимаю откуда берется комиссия (за доставку) 0.70 руб.

Comment: ищите в налогах, в  Учитывать В Доставке